# No newline after (sub)section?

Tags: sectioning, line-breaking

I want my text to appear right after the call to `\subsection{Name}` but  I can't find how to do it. I'm using the `article` class.

An example of command:

```
\subsection{a)} Blah blah bla...
```

produces:

> a)
>
> Blah blah bla...

instead of what I want:

> a) Blah blah bla...

Anything I could do?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469096/no-newline-after-subsection?noredirect=1) was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Your specific example can be solved by using the `enumerate` environment (as mentioned by elcelista), but your general question can be answered by using the [`titlesec`](https://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec?lang=en) package.  The `titlesec` package defines the `\titleformat` command which allows any sectioning command to be easily redefined.  The syntax of the `\titleformat` command is

```
\titleformat{command}[shape]{format}{label}{sep}{before}[after]
```

To eliminate the newline after a subsection heading, put the following in the preamble for your document:

```
\titleformat{\subsection}[runin]{}{}{}{}[]
```

Here is an example document and its output:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\subsection}[runin]{}{}{}{}[]

\begin{document}
\subsection*{a)}
Blah blah bla...
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of titlesec example]

Comment: Thanx a lot, this is exactly what I was looking for :)
I formated the subsection's name to bold with:
\titleformat{\subsection}[runin]{\bfseries}{}{}{}[]

Comment: Why there is an error if I unstar \subsection?

Comment: see https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Sections_and_chapters for another example of using \titleformat

Comment: I did not manage to apply your runin proposal for `\section`. The following however works with the replacement for `\section` http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8660/13173

Answer (score 7):

I don't know of any way to do that with (sub)section headings, but have you considered the `enumerate` environment? If you're trying to make an ordered list, you can do:

```
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\alph{enumi})}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item Blah blah bla...
  \item Next one
  \item etc.
\end{enumerate}
```

and you would get something like

> a) Blah blah bla...
>
> b) Next one
>
> c) etc.

Comment: I did and I was using this before, but I needed a TOC entry, so wanted to keep (sub)subsections.

Comment: You can also add a TOC entry anywhere you want with something like

\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Name}

Answer (score 4):

Just to add on the other answers, or maybe for other readers coming here:

If you just want some initial bold text, and suppress the newline, that is what `\paragraph{My title} Here some text.` would do. Also see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/130415/par-vs-paragraph).

Maybe you also want to define your custom section type (`\mysection{My title} ...` or so). This would be via package `titlesec` and `\titleclass` command. See [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/394112/define-new-section) for more.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure that I understand you problem. I am assuming that your `a)` is meant to be the subsection numbering, and that "Blah blah blah" is mean to be the title, and that you have not exhibited the text of the subsection at all.

Subsection are numbered (lettered?) automatically, the argument is the title:

```
 \subsection{Blah blah blah}
 Then the text of the subsection...
```

will generate something like:

> 3.1 Blah blah blah
>
> Then the text of the subsection...

where the c)

To change the formatting of the subsection header, you either hack the class definition or choose a more flexible class (like [memoir](http://tug.ctan.org/cgi-bin/ctanPackageInformation.py?id=memoir)).

Answer (score 0):

Small addition to the first answer so you don't have to use for example `\subsection*{a)}`. You can reformat the subsection title using the `\titleformat` command and then modify the `\thesubsection` as you like separately.
I have used something like this to format both section and subsection titles:

```
\renewcommand{\thesection}{Problem \arabic{section}}

\titleformat{\subsection}[runin]{\normalfont\large}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{(\alph{subsection})}

\begin{document}

\section{\it{title}}
\subsection{} Some more text here
```

this will give you:

[image: code output]