# \par vs \paragraph

Tags: paragraphs, sections-paragraphs

What is the difference between `\par` and `\paragraph`? I can skip a space between two paragraphs and have it retained on in the output on XeLaTeX. How is the effect different from using `paragraph` environment?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

The `\par` command is used to end a paragraph. You can do the same thing by leaving a blank line (pressing Enter twice) in your document source.

The `\paragraph` command is a section heading. It is different from the higher section levels because it places its heading text in the first paragraph. For example, the code

```
\paragraph{Heading} This is my document text.
```

produces

> **Heading** This is my document text.

As far as I am aware, there is no `paragraph` environment--that is, a code construct beginning with `\begin{paragraph}` and ending with `\end{paragraph}`.