# \paragraph does not act as \section, the body text continues on the same line

Tags: sections-paragraphs

Hi My \paragraph after \subsubsection does not act as a section, the text continues on the same line as title. Please help.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/130415/par-vs-paragraph

Comment: This is the standard behaviour.

Comment: latex headings support both display and inline settings, by default article switches to inline for paragraph, but it is easy to change that,

Comment: Short answer: `\paragraph` is not `\section`.