# Question about headings

Tags: sectioning

I'm currently learning LaTeX and want to know how to make headings like in this document: http://www.math.northwestern.edu/~kra/papers/primes.pdf

Like 1. Introduction
2. etc
etc

I'm thinking that it's got to involve \section somehow and centering it
Thanks!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: \documentclass{amsart}
\title{\bf HAPPY DAY}
\author{L.~KP}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\centerline{1. INTRODUCTION}
Hello, this is the closest I can get to the above document provided on my original post
\end{document}

Comment: Forgot to add: See if the `amsart` document class does everything you need. I.e. `\documentclass{amsart}\begin{document}\section{Intro}etc.\end{document}`.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply, my TexStudio is lagging at the moment. I will get back to you when I try out that code you have provided me with!

Comment: WOW!!!! Thank you so much Torbjørn T! :)
I just tested out your code and it outputted something desirable. One more question: if I want to use LaTeX to compile a document for small proofs to help my friends (eg. why sqrt{2} is irrational), what is the most PROPER documentclass or page layout I should be using? 

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using [titlesec](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) as described on [No newline after (sub)section?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42943/no-newline-after-subsection) and especially http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=10456 my proposal is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}
       {\normalfont\bfseries\center}% formatting commands to apply to the whole section heading
       {\thesection .}% the label and number
       {0.5em}% space between label/number and section title
       {}% formatting commands applied just to section title
       []% punctuation or other commands following section title
\titleformat{\subsection}[runin]% runin puts it in the same paragraph
       {\normalfont\bfseries}% formatting commands to apply to the whole subsection heading
       {\thesubsection .}% the label and number
       {0.5em}% space between label/number and subsection title
       {}% formatting commands applied just to subsection title
       [.]% punctuation or other commands following subsection title
\begin{document}
        \section{This is a section}

        Some text following.

        \subsection{This is a subsection}

        Some more text following.
\end{document}
```

I hope that meets your requirements.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts but I already found what I need and is much simlper than your method of coding. Thanks again.

Comment: No problem. Could you please publish your solution?

Comment: Sorry, how do I 'publish' my solution? Do I just comment on here?

With help from Torbjon T.

\documentclass{amsart}\begin{document}\section{Intro}etc.\end{document}

Comment: I have no idea how to put larger pieces of code in a comment. Why not to create an answer and then to paste the code with the help editor of the answer function?

Comment: What are you on about..?