# Define new section

Tags: sectioning, fontsize, titlesec

Is there a way to define a new section that is similar to `\section` but with a different font size? Something like

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{mysection}{\large \section}
\begin{document}

\mysection{Section 1}

\end{document}
```

I don't want to change the font size of `\section` permanently.

Comment: Should it be numbered? Is it outside or inside a `\section`?  The easiest solution is to use the sectioning commands available and format them as you like using `titlesec`.

Comment: @AlanMunn yes it should be numbered and it's outside a `\section`. It should act exactly like `\section`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There really are a number of different ways to achieve what you want. Some are simpler than others and may work just as well.

### Use existing levels if possible

It really only makes sense to add a higher level to your document if you *also* need all of the lower levels of your document.  So for example, if your document requires 4 levels (one above `\section` and two below), then you can simply use `\section`, `\subsection`, `\subsubsection` and `\paragraph` as your four levels, and use the `titlesec` package to format them as you like.  This is really the simplest method. If you don't like the names you can always use `\let` to change them to something that matches your document semantics better.

### Use `report` class and redefine the `\chapter` command

Alternatively, you could use a class that has a division above section, such as the  `\report` class and redefine the format of the `\chapter` command to be your outside sectioning command. I've made the fontsize `\LARGE` as an example but you can change this as you require. The values for the spacing are taken from the `titlesec` documentation for the default class sectioning definitions.

If you don't like using `\chapter` for something that isn't a chapter, you can use `\let` to rename it to something that matches your document semantics, e.g.,  `\let\mysection\chapter`.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]
  {\normalfont\LARGE\sffamily\bfseries}{\thechapter}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{3.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{2.3 ex plus .2ex}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\chapter{A chapter}
\lipsum[1]
\section{A section}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

### Redefining the `\part` command in the `article` class

If you don't want to change the document class, you could also redefine the `\part` command which is above the `\section` level in `article` to be like a section:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleclass{\part}{straight}
\titleformat{\part}[hang]
  {\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries}{\thepart}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\part}{0pt}{3.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{2.3 ex plus .2ex}
\renewcommand{\thepart}{\arabic{part}}
\let\mysection\part
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\mysection{A chapter}
\lipsum[1]
\section{A section}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

### Creating a new titling level entirely

If you still need parts in your document, and all the levels below section you can create a new sectioning class entirely.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\newcounter{mysection}
\titleclass{\mysection}{straight}[\part]
\titleformat{\mysection}[hang]
  {\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries}{\themysection}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\mysection}{0pt}{3.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{2.3 ex plus .2ex}
\renewcommand{\themysection}{\arabic{mysection}}
\counterwithin{section}{mysection}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\mysection{A chapter}
\lipsum[1]
\section{A section}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

### Tables of contents

If you take the last option, you need to also tell the TOC about your new section if you are using a table of contents.  To do this, use the `titletoc` package which works nicely with `titlesec`. In this complete example I've added a new sectioning level between `\part` and `\section` and then defined its counter (with the help of the `chngcntr` package). I then use the `\titlecontents` command from `titletoc` to tell the TOC how to format the `\mysection` level.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\newcounter{mysection}
\titleclass{\mysection}{straight}[\part]
\titleformat{\mysection}[hang]
  {\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries}{\themysection}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\mysection}{0pt}{3.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{2.3 ex plus .2ex}
\renewcommand{\themysection}{\arabic{mysection}}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\themysection.\arabic{section}}
\counterwithin{section}{mysection}
\contentsmargin{1em}
\titlecontents*{mysection}[2em]{}{\bfseries\contentslabel{2em}}{}
{\titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\contentspage}[]
\dottedcontents{section}[4em]{}{2em}{.5pc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\mysection{My custom section}
\lipsum[1]
\section{A section}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Thank you! However, I would really like to keep the `\article` class, since it changes a lot of my formatting otherwise.

Comment: @lala_12 I've added two other solutions using `article` class.

Comment: Thank you! I get the error `Package hyperref Warning: bookmark level for unknown mysection defaults to 0`, but it still works.

Comment: I didn't see this before, but the table of contents cannot be displayed correctly.. Do you know how to change to bookmark level so it is looks like a subsection in the table of contents?

Comment: @lala_12 I've updated the answer. (You might also want to consider the first option I've added too.)

Comment: @AlanMunn: I have tried using your code, but inserting two mysection on a row, so
...
\mysection{A chapter} One
\mysection{another} Two
...
This gives an error: "Package titlesec Error: Entered in horizontal mode. \mysection{another}". What is going on?

Comment: @FilippoAlbertoEdoardo The code as posted works without error. The problem probably lies with your `titlesec` definitions, but without seeing your code it's not possible to diagnose. Make a minimal document that shows the problem and ask a new question, linking to this question as the source of the original code.

Comment: @AlanMunn Done in the question https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/516856/30052. Thanks!

Comment: @FilippoAlbertoEdoardo Thanks!  I've added an answer and updated this one too.