# Problem with titlesec and horizontal mode

Tags: titlesec

I am referring [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/394117/30052) where I the following solution was suggested. The code giving me an error is the following one (copied-pasted from my LaTeX editor):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\part}[hang]
  {\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries}{\thepart}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\part}{0pt}{3.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{2.3 ex plus .2ex}
\renewcommand{\thepart}{\arabic{part}}
\let\mysection\part
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\mysection{A chapter} one
\mysection{another} two
\section{A section}
\end{document}
```

The error I receive is `Package titlesec Error: Entered in horizontal mode. \mysection{another}`

Comment: Add a blank line between the two `\mysection`. This being said, why don't you use the `report` class; to have \chapter at your disposal?

Comment: I have noticed that adding a blank line does the job, but I am wondering where the problem lies. I don't need in particular any chapter or anything, I am trying to understand how sectioning works.

Comment: I wonder too. Yet, I've been using titlesec  for many years, but I really don't see for this one. Maybe some guru will know

Comment: Of course, a hack is to set
\def\mysection{\par\part}
instead of
\let\mysection\part
but this is really awful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem arises because `titlesec` doesn't touch definitions of `\part` which are usually non-standard across classes. I hadn't taken that into account in the original question.  The solution is to make `titlesec` redefine `\part` by explicitly giving it a class, using the `\titleclass` command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleclass{\part}{straight}
\titleformat{\part}[hang]
  {\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries}{\thepart}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\part}{0pt}{3.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{2.3 ex plus .2ex}
\renewcommand{\thepart}{\arabic{part}}
\let\mysection\part
\begin{document}
\mysection{A chapter}
one
\mysection{another}
two

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]