# Custom subsubsection interferes with existing subsubsection format

Tags: titlesec

I’m using `titlesec` to define a custom subsubsection heading, by adapting the answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/394112/define-new-section).

I would like `\mysubsubheading` to coexist with the existing `\subsubsection`, as an alternative style. But now when I use `\subsubheading`, the subsubsection numbering no longer appears as part of the formatting:

[image]

How do I define a new subsubsection style which doesn’t interfere with the existing one? I don’t need the two subsubsection styles to be usable within the same subsection simultaneously; rather, within a given subsection, I want to be able to choose betweeen using `\subsubsection` and `\mysubsubsection`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\newcounter{mysubsubsection}
\titleclass{\mysubsubsection}{straight}[\subsection]
\titleformat{\mysubsubsection}
  {\normalfont\bfseries}{WP \themysubsubsection:~}{0em}{}
\titlespacing*{\mysubsubsection}{0pt}{*3.25}{*1.5}
\counterwithin{subsection}{mysubsubsection}
\renewcommand{\themysubsubsection}{\arabic{mysubsubsection}}

\begin{document}
\subsection{subsection}
\subsubsection{subsubsection}
\mysubsubsection{My subsubsection}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you require the counters of subsubsection and mysubsubsection be distinct?

Comment: I think they can probably share a counter, since I don’t need them to cohabit the same subsection (and in the event that they did, it would be reasonable for them to share).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd just put the styles into macros which define them and then use those macros to toggle the style of the `\subsubsection` and won't use a custom `\mysubsubsection` macro:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\newcommand*\subsubsectionstyleA
  {%
    \titleformat\subsubsection
      {\normalfont\bfseries}
      {WP \thesubsubsection:~}
      {0pt}
      {}%
    \titlespacing*\subsubsection{0pt}{*3.25}{*1.5}%
    \renewcommand*\thesubsubsection{\arabic{subsubsection}}%
  }
\newcommand*\subsubsectionstyleB
  {%
    \titleformat\subsubsection
      {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}
      {\thesubsubsection}
      {1em}
      {}%
    \titlespacing*\subsubsection{0pt}{*3.25}{*1.5}%
    \renewcommand*\thesubsubsection{\thesubsection.\arabic{subsubsection}}%
  }


\begin{document}
\section{section}
\subsection{subsection}
\subsubsectionstyleA
\subsubsection{subsubsection}
\subsubsection{subsubsection}

\subsection{subsection}
\subsubsectionstyleB
\subsubsection{subsubsection}
\subsubsection{subsubsection}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This way the subsubsection counts of the ones using styleA (your custom one) would just be displayed as `1`, `2`, etc. in the ToC. If you want the `WP` to also be included in the ToC, you could use the similar:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\newcommand*\subsubsectionstyleA
  {%
    \titleformat\subsubsection
      {\normalfont\bfseries}
      {\thesubsubsection:~}
      {0pt}
      {}%
    \titlespacing*\subsubsection{0pt}{*3.25}{*1.5}%
    \renewcommand*\thesubsubsection{WP~\arabic{subsubsection}}%
  }
\newcommand*\subsubsectionstyleB
  {%
    \titleformat\subsubsection
      {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}
      {\thesubsubsection}
      {1em}
      {}%
    \titlespacing*\subsubsection{0pt}{*3.25}{*1.5}%
    \renewcommand*\thesubsubsection{\thesubsection.\arabic{subsubsection}}%
  }


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{section}
\subsection{subsection}
\subsubsectionstyleA
\subsubsection{subsubsection}
\subsubsection{subsubsection}

\subsection{subsection}
\subsubsectionstyleB
\subsubsection{subsubsection}
\subsubsection{subsubsection}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, and also to @Bernard for the useful answers. I prefer this one because it generalises more easily to more than two styles. I also need this to work with section numbers placed (right-justified) in the left margin; I’ll ask a separate question for that, since I’m not sure how to do that with `titlesec`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using a boolean (`prefix`) in `\titleformat`. Note, however, that the prefix is not incorporated in the table of contents (I think it could be with `titletoc`. Not tested, though).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[toctitles]{titlesec}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newbool{prefix}

\titleformat{\subsubsection}
  {\normalfont\bfseries}{\ifbool{prefix}{WP~\thesubsubsection\,:}{\thesubsubsection}}{0.5em}{}
\titlespacing*{\mysubsubsection}{0pt}{*3.25}{*1.5}

\newcommand{\mysubsubsection}[2][]{\booltrue{prefix}\subsubsection[#1]{#2}\boolfalse{prefix}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsubsection{A normal subsubsection}
Some text.
\mysubsubsection{My subsubsection}
Some more text.
\subsubsection{Subsubsection}
Some text again.
\mysubsubsection{Another subsubsection}
Still some more text.

\end{document}
```

[image]