# Subsubsection: remove the newline (like paragraph)

Tags: sectioning, formatting, sections-paragraphs

Using the article document class, how can one remove the newline at the end of a subsubsection title?

I am using `\documentclass{article}`; I do not currently use `titlesec` or any of the alternatives; I do use `fancyhdr`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Without any additional packages, you need to update the *fifth* argument to `\@startsection` and make it *negative* - implicitly passed with a call to `\subsubsection`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\section{A section} Some text
\subsection{A subsection} Some text
\subsubsection{A subsubsection} Some text

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\subsubsection{\@startsection{subsubsection}{3}{\z@}%
                                     {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                     {-1.5ex \@plus -.2ex}% Formerly 1.5ex \@plus .2ex
                                     {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\makeatother

\section{A section} Some text
\subsection{A subsection} Some text
\subsubsection{A subsubsection} Some text
\end{document}
```

---

This may seem like *magic*... that is, why the *fifth* argument, and why does it have to be negative. To see why, you have to follow the chain of execution within the [LaTeX kernel](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/latex.ltx). The relevant code addressing this is contained within `\@startsection` and `\@sect`:

```
\def\@startsection#1#2#3#4#5#6{%
  \if@noskipsec \leavevmode \fi
  \par
  \@tempskipa #4\relax
  \@afterindenttrue
  \ifdim \@tempskipa <\z@
    \@tempskipa -\@tempskipa \@afterindentfalse
  \fi
  \if@nobreak
    \everypar{}%
  \else
    \addpenalty\@secpenalty\addvspace\@tempskipa
  \fi
  \@ifstar
    {\@ssect{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}}%
    {\@dblarg{\@sect{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}}}}
\def\@sect#1#2#3#4#5#6[#7]#8{%
  \ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth
    \let\@svsec\@empty
  \else
    \refstepcounter{#1}%
    \protected@edef\@svsec{\@seccntformat{#1}\relax}%
  \fi
  \@tempskipa #5\relax
  \ifdim \@tempskipa>\z@
    \begingroup
      #6{%
        \@hangfrom{\hskip #3\relax\@svsec}%
          \interlinepenalty \@M #8\@@par}%
    \endgroup
    \csname #1mark\endcsname{#7}%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{#1}{%
      \ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth \else
        \protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}%
      \fi
      #7}%
  \else
    \def\@svsechd{%
      #6{\hskip #3\relax
      \@svsec #8}%
      \csname #1mark\endcsname{#7}%
      \addcontentsline{toc}{#1}{%
        \ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth \else
          \protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}%
        \fi
        #7}}%
  \fi
  \@xsect{#5}}
```

In the above code, keep the focus on the fifth argument, denoted by `#5` in `\@startsection`. Although nothing happens to it inside `\@startsection`, it passes `#5` also as the *fifth* argument to `\@sect`. So, inside `\@sect`, `#5` is the length stored in `\@tempskipa` and subsequently evaluated using

```
\ifdim \@tempskipa>\z@
%... \@tempskipa (or #5) is positive
\else
%... \@tempskipa (or #5) is negative
\fi
```

The evaluation references `\z@` or `0pt` (see [What does `\z@` do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55400/5764)) and therefore designates a choice between `\@tempskipa` being positive or negative. The construction inside `\else` is what you're after, since it does not include a `\@@par` (or line/paragraph break). As a comparison, see the definition of `\paragraph`:

```
\newcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}%
                                    {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex}%
                                    {-1em}%
                                    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
```

Note that argument `#5` is negative (`-1em`).

A brief summary of the above discussion is included in the [kernel documentation](http://www.tug.org/texlive/Contents/live/texmf-dist/doc/latex/base/source2e.pdf), also covered in [Where can I find help files or documentation for commands like `\@startsection` for LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31780/5764)

Using packages like [`titlesec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) removes this *magic* in a more user-friendly way. For an example, see [Subsection starting in same line as subsection name](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/164333/5764).

Comment: I did not manage to get `\makeletter ...` work for `\section` but this works http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8660/13173