# Adjusting section titles with additional texts

Tags: sectioning

I want to write a statement about the current status of some topics (which are in sections/subsections) right aligned with the corresponding section/subsection title. For example, see the figure:

[image]

I did this with:
`\section{Zeroth Topic} \vspace*{-2.25em} \hfill \textit{Not started} \\ Some text goes here.`

But what is a simpler way? I need such status statements against some of the section/subsection titles. Here's a minimal working example to start with:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

    \section{Zeroth Topic} \vspace*{-2.25em} \hfill \textit{Not started} \\
    Some text goes here.

    \section{First topic}       \textit{Completed}
    Some text goes here.

    \section{Second topic}      \textit{Not started}
    Some text goes here.

    \section{Third topic}       % no comment
    Some text goes here.

    \section{Fourth topic}      % no comment
    Some text goes here.

        \subsection{First Subtopic}     \textit{Minor progress}
        Some text goes here.

        \subsection{Second Subtopic}            % no comment
        Some text goes here.

\end{document}
```

Comment: This shouts at you: Use a redefinition of the `\section` command ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I saw http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/164333/subsection-starting-in-same-line-as-subsection-name but I don't need comment for each subsection

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This feature can be added easily using an 2nd optional argument to the `\section` and `\subsection` commands, which is used for the 'status'.

This does no harm if the argument is empty.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\makeatletter
\let\latex@@section\section
\let\latex@@subsection\subsection




\RenewDocumentCommand{\section}{somO{}}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{% Is it the starred version (s)?
    \latex@@section*{#3}%
  }{% Nope
    \IfValueTF{#2}{% Is the 2nd optional argument in action?
      \latex@@section[#2]{#3\hfill\textit{#4}}
    }{% No 2nd optional argument, write `#3` to the ToC instead.
      \latex@@section[#3]{#3\hfill\textit{#4}}
    }%
  }%
}

\RenewDocumentCommand{\subsection}{somO{}}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
    \latex@@subsection*{#3}%
  }{%
    \IfValueTF{#2}{%
      \latex@@subsection[#2]{#3\hfill\textit{#4}}
    }{%
      \latex@@subsection[#3]{#3\hfill\textit{#4}}
    }%
  }%
}


\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

    \section{Zeroth Topic}[Not started]
    Some text goes here.

    \section{First topic}[Completed]
    Some text goes here.

    \section{Second topic}[Not started]
    Some text goes here.

    \section{Third topic}       % no comment
    Some text goes here.

    \section{Fourth topic}      % no comment
    Some text goes here.

    \subsection{First Subtopic}[Minor progress]

    Some text goes here.

    \subsection{Second Subtopic}
    Some text goes here.
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update**

A version which allows switching off `status` content:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\makeatletter
\let\latex@@section\section
\let\latex@@subsection\subsection

\newif\ifusestatus

\usestatustrue




\RenewDocumentCommand{\section}{somO{}}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
    \latex@@section*{#3}%
  }{%
    \ifusestatus
    \edef\@@tempa@@{#4}
    \else
    \edef\@@tempa@@{}
    \fi
    \IfValueTF{#2}{%
      \latex@@section[#2]{#3\hfill\textit{\@@tempa@@}}
    }{%
      \latex@@section[#3]{#3\hfill\textit{\@@tempa@@}}
    }%
  }%
}

\RenewDocumentCommand{\subsection}{somO{}}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
    \latex@@subsection*{#3}%
  }{%
    \ifusestatus
    \edef\@@tempa@@{#4}
    \else
    \edef\@@tempa@@{}
    \fi
    \IfValueTF{#2}{%
      \latex@@subsection[#2]{#3\hfill\textit{\@@tempa@@}}
    }{%
      \latex@@subsection[#3]{#3\hfill\textit{\@@tempa@@}}
    }%
  }%
}


\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

    \section{Zeroth Topic}[Not started]
    Some text goes here.

    \section{First topic}[Completed]
    Some text goes here.

    \section{Second topic}[Not started]
    Some text goes here.

    \section{Third topic}       % no comment
    Some text goes here.

    \section{Fourth topic}      % no comment
    Some text goes here.

    \subsection{First Subtopic}[Minor progress]

    Some text goes here.

    \subsection{Second Subtopic}
    Some text goes here.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Well, what to do if I want a comment even for starred sections?

Comment: @pushpen.paul: `\latex@@section*{#3\hfill\textit{#4}}` (and similar for `subsection` then

Comment: Great, thanks. I adjusted with `\normalfont\normalsize`.

Comment: @pushpen.paul: Of course, that's your choice