# In LyX, how can I remove the title and newline in a subsubsection?

Tags: sectioning, lyx, koma-script, sections-paragraphs

I'm using the KOMA-script article class (`\documentclass{scrartcl}`)and would like to remove the title and newline from the subsubsection, leaving me with a number followed by standard text.

Ideally I'd like to add something to the preamble once, but I can add something at each subsubsection if I need to. I'm also open to other document classes.

I'm seeing that the package `\titlesec` might be able to do what I want to do, but I'm not seeing any clear examples of it.

I'm new here, and to LaTeX, so please let me know how to better format or ask this question (for future questions as I dig deeper into LyX and actual LaTeX).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Thanks for fixing my tags folks. I'll make sure to be more complete in future questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the line where your subsubsection title should be, do Insert-->Short title and leave that box empty. That takes care of the title. To take away the skip after the subsubsection number, add this to the preamble (thanks to @Werner [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/122465/44524)):

```
\renewcommand\subsubsection{\@startsection{subsubsection}{3}{\z@}%
                                     {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                     {-1.5ex \@plus -.2ex}% Formerly 1.5ex \@plus .2ex
                                     {\normalfont\sectfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
```

Please note that these empty-title subsubsections are not showing on the Table of Contents. If that is an issue, I suggest you follow up this question with another one.

Comment: I saw @Werner's post, but didn't know how to apply it. And the Short-title works great. Thanks for your help. Works exactly like I needed.